# button visible with selecting tabpage c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a form with three buttons and a tabcontrol which has three tabpages.

The buttons are placed outside the tabcontrol. I want `button1` to be visible when tabpage1 selected, `button2` visible when tabpage2 is selected and `button3` visible when tabpage3 is selected.

The code I currently have is as follows:

```
button1.Visible = false;
button2.Visible = false;
button3.Visible = false;

if (tabControl1.SelectedTab == tabPage1)
 { button1.Visible = true; } 

else if (tabControl1.SelectedTab == tabPage2)
 { button2.Visible = true; }

else if (tabControl1.SelectedTab == tabPage3) 
 { button3.Visible = true; }
```

This code isn't working.

The code i tried with `.Enabled` didnt work too. I am using visual studio 2010 and i drag n drop a tabcontrol with three tabpages and three buttons also are `OUTSIDE` of the tabcontrol. This isnt working too.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    button1.Enabled = false;
    button2.Enabled = false;
    button3.Enabled = false;

    if (tabControl1.SelectedTab == tabPage1){
        button1.Enabled = true;
        button2.Enabled = false;
        button3.Enabled = false;
    } else if (tabControl1.SelectedTab == tabPage2){
        button1.Enabled = false;
        button2.Enabled = true;
        button3.Enabled = false;
    } else if (tabControl1.SelectedTab == tabPage3){
        button1.Enabled = false;
        button2.Enabled = false;
        button3.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a bit more information - what isn't working exactly? Are you getting an exception or is it just that nothing happens? Also, have you tried setting `enabled` instead of `visible` just to check if the buttons are being modified at all?

Comment: What is the output? Do you see any button?

Comment: @Gabber there are three buttons `button1` enabled the others not. Whichever tabpage you choose the result is not changing. Thanks to your kind help.

Answer (score 2):

```
button1.Visible = tabControl1.SelectedTab == tabPage1;
button2.Visible = tabControl1.SelectedTab == tabPage2;
button3.Visible = tabControl1.SelectedTab == tabPage3;
```